# Moveable/draggable <div>

Tags: javascript, draggable, move, mousemove

This is my updated and modified script, it works completely, except I would like to universalize it... observe the **** how can I make it so that I don't have to do `function(e){BOX.Draggable.elemen = e.target || e.srcElement; elementDraggable(e);` everytime I need to use the dragable function for a different element?

```
window.onload = addListeners;

var BOX = function(){
  return{
    Draggable: function(){}
  };
}();

function addListeners(){
  document.getElementById('div').addEventListener('contextmenu', menumove, false);
  **document.getElementById('div').addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){BOX.Draggable.elemen = e.target || e.srcElement; elementDraggable(e);}, false);**
}

function elementDraggable(e){
  var e = e || window.event;
  var div = BOX.Draggable.elemen;
  BOX.Draggable.innerX = e.clientX + window.pageXOffset - div.offsetLeft;
  BOX.Draggable.innerY = e.clientY + window.pageYOffset - div.offsetTop;

  window.addEventListener('mousemove', elementMove, false);
  window.addEventListener('mouseup', function(){
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', elementMove, false);
    }, true);

  function elementMove(e){
    div.style.position = 'absolute';
    div.style.left = e.clientX + window.pageXOffset - BOX.Draggable.innerX + 'px';
    div.style.top = e.clientY + window.pageYOffset - BOX.Draggable.innerY + 'px';
  }
}
```

Comment: This post has a much simpler JS version https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24050738/javascript-how-to-dynamically-move-div-by-clicking-and-dragging

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Is jQuery an option for you? It makes what you are doing really simple since the code already exists.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wfbY8/4/)**

JavaScript Code

```
window.onload = addListeners;

function addListeners(){
    document.getElementById('dxy').addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);

}

function mouseUp()
{
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', divMove, true);
}

function mouseDown(e){
  window.addEventListener('mousemove', divMove, true);
}

function divMove(e){
    var div = document.getElementById('dxy');
  div.style.position = 'absolute';
  div.style.top = e.clientY + 'px';
  div.style.left = e.clientX + 'px';
}​
```

Comment: I already know how to do this with jquery, I am trying to learn how to do it manually with javascript, thanks.

Comment: yea, it didn't save the latest i i just realized it. I'm rewriting it

Comment: Ok. it should be fine now. I can't believe it didn't update it the first time and lost it.

Comment: Thanks, I had already figured out most of it, the only part I didn't have was the `removeEventListener` on `mouseup` part.

Comment: I noticed that the mouse "jumps" to the upper left corner of the div when dragging it - how can I fix this?

Comment: @AndersonGreen You have to take into account the position where the drag starts. If you start dragging from the middle of the div you have to offset the position by that. See http://jsfiddle.net/wfbY8/737/ (old comment I know, but needing a reply..)

Comment: jquery ui is very heavy! you should not install a full library for one simple thing. i kno that jquery ui is easy to use but we as developers have to start thinking in terms of "small".. especially for mobile.

Comment: That's true MrRioku but if he was already loading the library that would have been his best option. He wasn't so I provided him with straight JavaScript code.

Comment: Is there any reason why the functions `mouseDown` and `mouseUp` have the `useCapture` parameter set to `true` when attaching events?  While the `addListeners` function use `false`  when attaching events?

Answer (score 67):

This is a nice no-jQuery script to drag a div: http://jsfiddle.net/g6m5t8co/1/

```js
var mydragg = function() {
  return {
    move: function(divid, xpos, ypos) {
      divid.style.left = xpos + 'px';
      divid.style.top = ypos + 'px';
    },
    startMoving: function(divid, container, evt) {
      evt = evt || window.event;
      var posX = evt.clientX,
        posY = evt.clientY,
        divTop = divid.style.top,
        divLeft = divid.style.left,
        eWi = parseInt(divid.style.width),
        eHe = parseInt(divid.style.height),
        cWi = parseInt(document.getElementById(container).style.width),
        cHe = parseInt(document.getElementById(container).style.height);
      document.getElementById(container).style.cursor = 'move';
      divTop = divTop.replace('px', '');
      divLeft = divLeft.replace('px', '');
      var diffX = posX - divLeft,
        diffY = posY - divTop;
      document.onmousemove = function(evt) {
        evt = evt || window.event;
        var posX = evt.clientX,
          posY = evt.clientY,
          aX = posX - diffX,
          aY = posY - diffY;
        if (aX < 0) aX = 0;
        if (aY < 0) aY = 0;
        if (aX + eWi > cWi) aX = cWi - eWi;
        if (aY + eHe > cHe) aY = cHe - eHe;
        mydragg.move(divid, aX, aY);
      }
    },
    stopMoving: function(container) {
      var a = document.createElement('script');
      document.getElementById(container).style.cursor = 'default';
      document.onmousemove = function() {}
    },
  }
}();
```

```css
#container {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
}

#elem {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: green;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div id='container' style="width: 600px;height: 400px;top:50px;left:50px;">
  <div id="elem" onmousedown='mydragg.startMoving(this,"container",event);' onmouseup='mydragg.stopMoving("container");' style="width: 200px;height: 100px;">
    <div style='width:100%;height:100%;padding:10px'>
      <select id=test>
        <option value=1>first
          <option value=2>second
      </select>
      <INPUT TYPE=text value="123">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great solution! It's quite generic and also makes sure you cannot move the div outside the parent container!

Comment: Yep great example! Another issue with it is that if you start dragging and move cursor outside the green box mouse up does not register....in other words mouse up event does not register outside the green box.

Comment: Davvit, add 'onmouseout' for container.

Comment: What's the use of the `var a = document.createElement('script');` line in the `stopMoving` function?

Comment: this is way simpler: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24050738/javascript-how-to-dynamically-move-div-by-clicking-and-dragging

Comment: I really appreciate your code! Currently I'm using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24050738/javascript-how-to-dynamically-move-div-by-clicking-and-dragging/24050777#comment118592751_24050777 which I think is a simpler way to start and learn this. Next, inspired by yours, I want to block dragging past boundaries.

Answer (score 14):

After trying jnoreiga's accepted answer, I found it very annoying that the dragged element abruptly snapped to the top left corner, rather than maintaining the same relative position.

This snippet prevents the awkward aforementioned behavior via an offset, and provides a simple interface to create draggable elements one at a time or en masse via a `forEach` call or similar.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  draggable(document.getElementById('foo'));
}

function draggable(el) {
  el.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    var offsetX = e.clientX - parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(this).left);
    var offsetY = e.clientY - parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(this).top);
    
    function mouseMoveHandler(e) {
      el.style.top = (e.clientY - offsetY) + 'px';
      el.style.left = (e.clientX - offsetX) + 'px';
    }

    function reset() {
      window.removeEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveHandler);
      window.removeEventListener('mouseup', reset);
    }

    window.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveHandler);
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', reset);
  });
}
```

```css
/* The only required styling is position: absolute */
#foo {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Prevents inconsistent highlighting of element while being dragged
   Copied from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782 */
.noselect {
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
            user-select: none; /* Every other browser */
}
```

```html
<div id="foo" class="noselect">This is a draggable div!</div>
```

Comment: This is really easy to follow and use. The only change I made in 2024 was to switch everything to pointer events

Comment: As of January 2020, MDN says [user-select compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select#browser_compatibility) is universal except for Safari, so you can just do `-webkit-user-select:none; user-select:none`

Answer (score 13):

I modified [Shaedo's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41698549/1061155) code a little bit, wraps it in a function and add a feature that you can drag an element by only parts of it or its children, say the title bar of a div. Note in this demo, you can only drag the red area to move the blue area.

```js
function makeDragable(dragHandle, dragTarget) {
  // used to prevent dragged object jumping to mouse location
  let xOffset = 0;
  let yOffset = 0;

  let handle = document.querySelector(dragHandle);
  handle.addEventListener("mousedown", startDrag, true);
  handle.addEventListener("touchstart", startDrag, true);

  /*sets offset parameters and starts listening for mouse-move*/
  function startDrag(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    let dragObj = document.querySelector(dragTarget);
    
    // shadow element would take the original place of the dragged element, this is to make sure that every sibling will not reflow in the document
    let shadow = dragObj.cloneNode();
    shadow.id = ""
    // You can change the style of the shadow here
    shadow.style.opacity = 0.5
    dragObj.parentNode.insertBefore(shadow, dragObj.nextSibling);

    let rect = dragObj.getBoundingClientRect();
    dragObj.style.left = rect.left;
    dragObj.style.top = rect.top;
    dragObj.style.position = "absolute";
    dragObj.style.zIndex = 999999;

    /*Drag object*/
    function dragObject(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      if(e.type=="mousemove") {
        dragObj.style.left = e.clientX-xOffset + "px"; // adjust location of dragged object so doesn't jump to mouse position
        dragObj.style.top = e.clientY-yOffset + "px";
      } else if(e.type=="touchmove") {
        dragObj.style.left = e.targetTouches[0].clientX-xOffset +"px"; // adjust location of dragged object so doesn't jump to mouse position
        dragObj.style.top = e.targetTouches[0].clientY-yOffset +"px";
      }
    }
    /*End dragging*/
    document.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
      // hide the shadow element, but still let it keep the room, you can delete the shadow element to let the siblings reflow if that is what you want
      shadow.style.opacity = 0
      shadow.style.zIndex = -999999
      window.removeEventListener('mousemove', dragObject, true);
      window.removeEventListener('touchmove', dragObject, true);
    }, true)

    if (e.type=="mousedown") {
      xOffset = e.clientX - rect.left; //clientX and getBoundingClientRect() both use viewable area adjusted when scrolling aka 'viewport'
      yOffset = e.clientY - rect.top;
      window.addEventListener('mousemove', dragObject, true);
    } else if(e.type=="touchstart") {
      xOffset = e.targetTouches[0].clientX - rect.left;
      yOffset = e.targetTouches[0].clientY - rect.top;
      window.addEventListener('touchmove', dragObject, true);
    }
  }
}

makeDragable('#handle1', '#moveable1')
makeDragable('#handle2', '#moveable2')
makeDragable('#handle3', '#moveable3')
```

```css
.moveable {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
    display: inline-block
}

.handle {
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    cursor: move;
    background: red;
}

#moveable2 { background: green }
#moveable3 { background: teal }
```

```html
<div id="moveable1" class="moveable">
    <div id="handle1" class="handle">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="moveable2" class="moveable">
    <div id="handle2" class="handle">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="moveable3" class="moveable">
    <div id="handle3" class="handle">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This should definitely be the accepted answer: generic in it's approach, easy to use and even supports touch events. Oh, and it takes into account that often the container to drag will be different from the handle you're dragging it with. Thanks a lot!! :)

Answer (score 12):

Well, your movement code simplifies to:

```
div.style.position = "absolute";
div.style.top = e.clientY - (e.clientY - div.offsetTop) + "px";
div.style.left = e.clientX - (e.clientX - div.offsetLeft) + "px";
```

Basic math here - the `e.clientX` and `e.clientY` have absolutely no effect on the position here, so you're just taking the `offsetLeft` and reassigning it to the `style.left`, and the same for the top. Thus no movement whatsoever.

What you need to do is save the `clientX` and `clientY` when the `mousedown` happens, and do the subtraction based on that.

Oh and you're also setting the event listener wrong. The way it is now, you have it run `divMove` once and the return value (`undefined` here) is the function attached as the listener. Instead, use `function(e) {divMove(dxy,e || window.event);}`.

Comment: I mostly understand what you're saying and I can see that you're right. But i'm not exactly sure how to change it to what you're saying. could you put up a snippet to show me exactly what you mean?

Comment: You said in a comment to the other answer that you're trying to learn, so I won't do it for you, but basically you have two main ways of doing it. 1) Use absolute positioning, get the current mouse coordinates and set the element to those coordinates. 2) Use relative positioning, and take the difference between the current position and the start position.

Comment: Thanks, for making me do it on my own. I was able to figure out almost everything, and just needed a little bit of help because I didn't know about the `removeEventListener` method :-)

Comment: Yay ^_^ My own drag-and-drop code just uses `elem.onmousemove`, setting it to `null` instead of `removeEventListener`. Personal preference.

Answer (score 2):

For all my friends:

```
    function initDrag(div) {
        div.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
            if (e.target === div){
                startDrag(e, div);
            };
        });
    };

    function startDrag(e, div) {

        const offsetX = e.offsetX;
        const offsetY = e.offsetY;

        const controller = new AbortController();

        div.style.cursor = "grabbing";

        document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
            div.style.top = window.scrollY + e.clientY - offsetY + 'px';
            div.style.left = window.scrollX + e.clientX - offsetX + 'px';
        }, { signal: controller.signal }, true);

        'mouseup,blur'.split(',').forEach(e => {
            document.addEventListener(e, () => {
                controller.abort();
                div.style.cursor = "grab";
            }, { once: true }, true);
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Any solution that uses `clientY`, `clientX`, `pageY`, or `pageX` within the `dragend` event ***will completely fail in Firefox.***  Source: [Bugzilla: Bug #505521, Set screen coordinates during HTML5 drag event](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=505521#c80).

How do we get by this limitation?  `document`'s `drop` event *also fires* at the same exact time as the `dragend` event of the dragged element.  But, we can see things like `clientY` and `clientX` here in firefox.  So, let's just use that.

***Two working demos, 100% JavaScript-Only Solution***: SO Code Snippet and [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/hiyabib/edit?html,css,js,console,output).

```js
var startx = 0;
var starty = 0;
dragStartHandler = function(e) {
  startx = e.clientX;
  starty = e.clientY;
}

dragOverHandler = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
}

dragEndHandler = function(e) {
  if(!startx || !starty) {
    return false;
  }
  
  var diffx = e.clientX - startx;
  var diffy = e.clientY - starty;
  
  var rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();

var offset = { 
                top: rect.top + window.scrollY, 
                left: rect.left + window.scrollX, 
            };
  
  var newleft = offset.left + diffx;
  var newtop = offset.top + diffy;
  
  e.target.style.position = 'absolute';
  e.target.style.left = newleft + 'px';
  e.target.style.top = newtop + 'px';
  
  startx = 0;
  starty = 0;
}

document.getElementsByClassName("draggable")[0].addEventListener('dragstart', dragStartHandler);

document.addEventListener('dragover', dragOverHandler);
document.addEventListener('drop', dragEndHandler);
```

```css
.draggable {
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: move;
  width:250px;
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <BR><BR><BR>

  <div id="draggable1" class="draggable" draggable="true">
    Hey, try to drag this element!
  </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

**Explanation:**

- `dragStartHandler()` : This is bound to the draggable element.  Here, all we do is record the current x/y coordinates at start.
- `dragOverHandler()` : This is bound to the document, so that we can override the default dragover behavior.  This is needed to do any type of drag & dropping.
- `dragEndHandler()` : This is bound to the `document`'s `drop`.  Normally, we would want this to bind to the `element`'s `dragend`, but since `clientY` and `clientX` are missing, we bind it to the document.  This just does exactly what you'd want to happen when dragend is called, except you have x/y coordinates.

The formula used is:

```
set style to: (current position) - (original position)
```

That is as complicated as it gets, but to calculate and apply the style, just for the x-dimension, the code is...

```
var diffx = e.clientX - startx;
var rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
var offset = { 
        left: rect.left + window.scrollX, 
    };
var newleft = offset.left + diffx;
e.target.style.position = 'absolute';
e.target.style.left = newleft + 'px';
```

Answer (score 1):

This is modified @evan answer, it add `handle`

```js
function draggable(container, handle) {
    let movable = handle ? handle : container;
    ['mousedown', 'touchstart'].forEach(event => {
        movable.addEventListener(event, e => {
            var offsetX = e.clientX - parseInt(getComputedStyle(container).left);
            var offsetY = e.clientY - parseInt(getComputedStyle(container).top);

            function mouseMoveHandler(e) {
                container.style.top = (e.clientY - offsetY) + 'px';
                container.style.left = (e.clientX - offsetX) + 'px';
            }

            function reset() {
                removeEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveHandler);
                removeEventListener('mouseup', reset);
            }

            addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveHandler);
            addEventListener('mouseup', reset);
        });
    })
}

// box only
let boxOnly = document.querySelector('#boxOnly');
draggable(boxOnly);

// box with handle
let container = document.querySelector('#foo');
let header = document.querySelector('#foo .header')
draggable(container, header);
```

```css
/* The only required styling is position: absolute */
#foo, #boxOnly {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid black;
  user-select: none;
}
#boxOnly{left: 300px;}
.header { background: orange;margin: 0;text-align:center;  padding: 6px;}
p.header:active, div#boxOnly:active {cursor:move;}
```

```html
<div id="foo">
  <p class="header">Header</p>
  <p>Content cannot be dragged, <br>use header</p>
</div>

<div id="boxOnly">
  <p>Content can be dragged</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

An additional method to "niente00" code.

```
init : function(className){
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
        elements[i].onmousedown = function(){mydragg.startMoving(this,'container',event);};
        elements[i].onmouseup = function(){mydragg.stopMoving('container');};
        }
    }
```