# How to resize parent by dragging one of it's children?

Tags: html, drag-and-drop, draggable, drag

Essentially i want to resize the green box by dragging the blue thing.
[image: how to resize an element by dragging it's children]

I'm trying to use `OffsetLeft` but is not working. also the drag event doesn't fire in Firefox.

And i have the code here: [jsbin link](https://jsbin.com/lasurogase/edit?html,css,output)

```
<div id="parent">
   
 <div draggable="true" id="child" ondrag="dragging(event)" ></div>
 
</div>

<script>
   const parent = document.getElementById('parent');
   const child = document.getElementById('child');

   function dragging(event) {
     console.log("dragging");
     parent.style.width = child.offsetLeft;
   }

 </script>
```

and css:

```
/* green box */
#parent{
  position:absolute; -- notice the parent is absolute positioned. (not sure if it has an impact on how it works - but i need it to be absolute.
  top: 100;
  left: 100;
  background-color: green;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

/* blue bar */
#child{
  width: 5px;
  background-color: blue;
  cursor: e-resize;
}
```

So how can i do this, and also be `cross-browser compatible`?
I need a `html5 + js` solution - because i will use the logic for another programming language called `elm`. I can only read stuff form the DOM, not mutate it. So I can't work with already built libraries like Jquery.

Thanks for your interest.

Comment: The main issue is you need to add a unit as well, like this `child.offsetLeft + 'px';`

Comment: @LGSon ha ha, good catch, thank you. Still the general approach is bad, because dragging the blue line - doesn't change the `offsetLeft` at all - it's counter intuitive - i need a different approach.

Comment: You shoud use `event.pageX` ... posted an answer and is now checking why FF won't play along

Answer (score 1):

You should use `event.pageX` to get the correct value (and use a unit :)

This won't work on Firefox though: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=505521

```js
const parent = document.getElementById('parent');
const child = document.getElementById('child');

function dragging(event) {
  console.log("dragging");
  parent.style.width = event.pageX + 'px';
}

function dragStart(event) {
  event.dataTransfer.setData("Text", event.target.id);
}
```

```css
/* green box */

#parent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100;
  left: 100;
  background-color: green;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}


/* blue bar */

#child {
  width: 5px;
  background-color: blue;
  cursor: e-resize;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">

  <div draggable="true" id="child" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" ondrag="dragging(event)"></div>

</div>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

---

The old fashion way will work in Firefox though: [create-a-draggable-div-in-native-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13152578/create-a-draggable-div-in-native-javascript)

Comment: I like your answer - but i rely need a cross browser solution. I will wait a little bit more, before choosing the accepted answer.

Comment: @AIon Updated my answer with a link to another post showing the old fashion way to drag an element