# Allow select text on a HTML 5 draggable child element

Tags: html, css, html5-draggable

Having a table with draggable rows where each row is `draggable=true`, how can the user still **be able to select text** from a column?

```
<table>
 <thead>..</thead>
 <tbody>
  ..
  <tr draggable="true">
   <td>..</td>
   <td>Cool text but you can't select me</td>
   <td>..</td>
  </tr>
  ..
</tbody>
</table>
```

Another simple example (https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qjoBXV)

```
div {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  background: #eee;
}

.all-copy p {  
  -webkit-user-select: all;  /* Chrome all / Safari all */
  -moz-user-select: all;     /* Firefox all */
  -ms-user-select: all;      /* IE 10+ */
  user-select: all;          /* Likely future */   
}    
<div class="all-copy" draggable="true">
      <p>Select me as text</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: I don't know if it is just Mac browsers, but you can still select the text by right-clicking the element.

Comment: Also, I subjectively think it is better practice to have a clear and visually distinguished element for handling drag and drop rather than allowing to drag the whole row when you also need to select the text. The draggable area deserves a different cursor than selectable text at least.

Comment: Yeah, not sure about browsers running in Windows. Mozilla doc says that pressing Alt browser should allow to select the text but that never worked. Agree about the handler. I'm just following specs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to make that work, is to actually check which element fired the event, `e.target`, against the element that has the listener attach to itself, `#draggable` (in this case using `this`).

```
if (e.target === this) {...}
```

This will allow default behavior on element positioned inside the *draggable element*, such as selecting a text and so on.

***Note**, since [Firefox has issue with `draggable="true"`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44736344/how-to-resize-parent-by-dragging-one-of-its-children/44737844#44737844), I used a different drag method.*

Stack snippet

```js
(function (elem2drag) {
  var x_pos = 0, y_pos = 0, x_elem = 0, y_elem = 0;  
  
  document.querySelector('#draggable').addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    x_pos = e.pageX;
    y_pos = e.pageY;
    if (elem2drag !== null) {
        elem2drag.style.left = (x_pos - x_elem) + 'px';
        elem2drag.style.top = (y_pos - y_elem) + 'px';
    }  
  })

  document.querySelector('#draggable').addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    if (e.target === this) {
      elem2drag = this;
      x_elem = x_pos - elem2drag.offsetLeft;
      y_elem = y_pos - elem2drag.offsetTop;
      return false;
    }  
  })
  
  document.querySelector('#draggable').addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
    elem2drag = null;
  })
})(null);
```

```css
#draggable {
  display: inline-block;
  background: lightgray;
  padding:15px;
  cursor:move;
  position:relative;
}
span {
  background: white;
  line-height: 25px;
  cursor:auto;  
}
```

```html
<div id="draggable">
  <span>Select me as text will work<br>when the mouse is over the text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: What is `this` pointing at in this case?

Comment: @Ola -- Updated my answer to make it more clear how the solution works, and amongst other where `this` point at.

Answer (score 10):

**Updates for the `draggable` issue in Firefox. (Mar. 8, 2024)**

```js
// Allow the text in content can be selected.
contentEl.onmousedown = function(event) {
  itemEl.setAttribute("draggable", "false");
};

// Let the item be draggable again after the text selection is done.
contentEl.onmouseleave = function(event) {
  itemEl.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
};
```

Inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/31733408/6359074

---

There are two things we need to do.

- One thing is limitting the drag event only trigger on specified area, for example, the drag handle.
- The other thing is that we only set the text on the div with **content** class can be selected. The reason why we do so is that the element that has been set to draggable, on which browser will add a default rule **user-select: none**.

```js
const itemEl = document.querySelector('.item');
const contentEl = document.querySelector('.content');

let mouseDownEl;

itemEl.onmousedown = function(event) {
  mouseDownEl = event.target;
}

itemEl.ondragstart = function(event) {
  // Only the handle can be picked up to trigger the drag event.
  if (mouseDownEl.matches('.handle')) {
    // ...code
  } else {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}

/* 
 * The code below is just for the draggable issue in Firefox. 
 */  

// Allow the text in content can be selected.
contentEl.onmousedown = function(event) {
  itemEl.setAttribute("draggable", "false");
};

// Let the item be draggable again after the text selection is done.
contentEl.onmouseleave = function(event) {
  itemEl.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
};
```

```css
.item {
  width: 70px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

.content {
  border-top: 1px solid gray;
  user-select: text;
}
```

```html
<div class="item" draggable="true">
  <div class='handle'>handle</div>
  <div class='content'>content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note: This does not work in Firefox - selecting "content" won't drag the parent, but the text also won't be selected.

Comment: Removing draggable="true" from the HTML element and adding it in the mouseDownEl.matches('.handle') condition on mousedown event via JS should solve the Firefox issue.
draggable="true" should be removed again on mouseup event.

Comment: @kevlarr It is fixed.

Comment: @cadday Thanks for suggestion, but I use `mouseleave` event instead. When the mouse position is out of element in text selection, the `mouseup` event listener doesn't trigger. `mouseleave` event is safe here.

Comment: Nice @Neven.Leung, it does work for me now in FF