# Move Window in mfc c++ without titlebar?

Tags: html, c++, visual-studio-2013, mfc

I am using this code to move the window. But this code does not work well. When I click anywhere on windows from it will move but i just want to move windows form. When i click on specific think. For example picture. I am using MFC C++ HtmlDialog. Anyone know how to do that?

DHTML_EVENT_ONCLICK(_T("image"), PreTranslateMessage)

```
BOOL CHtmlDlgTestDlg::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
if (pMsg->message == WM_MOUSEMOVE && (pMsg->wParam & MK_LBUTTON))
{
    CPoint p;
    GetCursorPos(&p);
    CRect r;
    GetWindowRect(&r);
    if (r.PtInRect(p))
    {
        ReleaseCapture();
        SendMessage(WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HTCAPTION, 0);
        SendMessage(WM_NCLBUTTONUP, HTCAPTION, 0);
        return 1;
    }
}

return CDialog::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);    
}
```

Comment: It is really necessary to handle moving window inside of PreTranslateMessage ? I guess you can do this on OnLButtonDown, and OnMuseMove ...

Comment: SO Please Help me to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN` is a notification message, Windows sends this message and the program responds to it. The program should not send this message to Windows. In this case it works but it's not recommended.

I don't know how this code works: `DHTML_EVENT_ONCLICK(_T("image"), PreTranslateMessage)` it probably gets ignored and you can remove it. `PreTranslateMessage` is still called. You can restrict it to any rectangle within the Window, for example `CRect(50,50,200,200)`:

```
BOOL CHtmlDlgTestDlg::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
   if (pMsg->message == WM_MOUSEMOVE && (pMsg->wParam & MK_LBUTTON))
   {
       CPoint p = pMsg->pt;
       ScreenToClient(&p);
       CRect r(50,50,200,200);
       if (r.PtInRect(p))
       {
           ReleaseCapture();
           SendMessage(WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HTCAPTION, 0);
           SendMessage(WM_NCLBUTTONUP, HTCAPTION, 0);
           return 1;
       }
   }
   return CDialog::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}
```

If you want to move an element within the window you can use javascript:

[Moveable/draggable <div>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334084/moveable-draggable-div/25933582#25933582)

Ps, normally you should use **WM_NCHITTEST** as explained earlier. This case is very unusual because it's HTML dialog. You should reconsider putting a normal title bar which users understand, or you could put html control within a dialog, then you can control the rest of the dialog with standard WinApi.

Comment: Sir, How i can perform this task. When i just click on ok button. Mean When i press ok button then i am able to move window. Actually no press just push it down?

Comment: @MuhammadRaza: IMHO this is not the way to go. Use IInspectable's solution.

Comment: @MichaelWalz in this case `OnNcHitTest` doesn't work because it's an html dialog. Also the SO's requirement is unreasonablein trying to move html window by clicking OK button within the html window.

Comment: Sir, Barmak Shemirani. What i just want when i just press button ok down. I am able to move whole windows form any where in the screen. And if i click on any another place the windows is not going to move. You are correct OnNcHitTest is not work with Mfc html dialog.

Comment: @MuhammadRaza Get the coordinates of the OK button. If the coordinates are at `50,50,200,200` then the edit that I made should work.

Comment: Sir i understand you and thank you. You help me lot. Just one think which rectangle we make. How to color that one to black?

Comment: @MuhammadRaz I am not sure what you are referring to. You could just remove the OK button and put in a black rectangle instead, because the OK button is no longer functioning as OK button anyway.