# Restrict dragging of object inside html on specific div window using javascript

Tags: javascript, drag

I have used this script and I was wondering if it's possible to prevent the dragging of image when it is at the edge of the div window inside html?

Here is the link:

```
<https://jsfiddle.net/61t6nn4a/2/>
```

Any tips would be awesome thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your life easier by using jQuery.

jQueryUI has a draggable functionnality, check the documentation here : http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://www.zpixel.com/staging/test/image.png" class="dragme">
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(".dragme").draggable({
    containment: ".container"
});
```

Here is the JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/v28r9v3r/1/

Comment: Thank you will keep this! Although I'm trying to make this work via pure javascript due to client restrictions. Crap.

Comment: Well, you can check this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ryuofpaL/ It's from this guy: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25933582/6335043

Comment: Thanks Leo, but I might use the image as html, not background. Will see if this can be useful. Cheers!

Comment: If the answer resolved your problem, please mark it as the [correct answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) ;)