# Implementing movable <div> in Blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side

I am trying to implement as a component movable  in Blazor, but I am not sure how to translate the JavaScript to Blazor.
I am generally traying to achieve something like : https://stackoverflow.com/a/47596086/767942

- How to handle @onmousedown and translate it to Blazor in order to achive the movable < div > from the example above ?

Comment: `onmousedown` is available on Blazor. No JS needed. Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57306208/how-to-drag-an-image-by-mouse More info: https://chrissainty.com/investigating-drag-and-drop-with-blazor/

Comment: I've just went to the same idea (as keeping researching on it) as the examples you have posted, but both is rather chunky. The result is not smooth dragging feeling like in the example which i've pointed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is another way to do it using the `ondragstart` and `ondragend` event that I use to make a movable "popup window".

```
<div draggable="true"
     @ondragend="OnDragEnd" @ondragstart="OnDragStart"
     style="position:absolute; top: @(offsetY)px; left: @(offsetX)px; border-color: black;">
   <div>your content</div>
</div>

@code 
{
     private double startX, startY, offsetX, offsetY;

     private void OnDragStart(DragEventArgs args) {
         startX = args.ClientX;
         startY = args.ClientY;
 }

     private void OnDragEnd(DragEventArgs args)
 {
         offsetX += args.ClientX - startX;
         offsetY += args.ClientY - startY;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not smooth dragging like you can achieve with javascript though.